# Querying a Collection of One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

Suppose I have a `User` model and a `Post` model.

```
class Post extends Eloquent 
{

}
```

There are many users, and each `User` has many `Post`. All `Post` belongs to a `User`.

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

I know that I can get a single `User` with `find()`.

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

I know that from a single `User`, I can get all their `posts()`.

```
$posts = User::find(1)->posts;
```

However, suppose now I have multiple users.

```
$users = User::all();
```

I wish to access all the posts that this collection of users have. Something along the lines of

```
$posts = User::all()->posts;
```

This, of course, doesn't work. However, in theory, it should be functionally equivalent to

```
$posts = Post::all()
```

**Is there a way to do something similar to the above in Laravel 4.2?**

---

I do not want to use `Post::all()`. Reason being that it would not be what I want in a more complicated example that involves constraints on `User`.

```
$postsByMaleUsers = User::where('gender', '=', 'male')->posts;
```

Should get all the posts made by male users.

---

I am also aware that I could simply use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($users->posts as $post)
{
    // Process result here.
}
```

However, suppose I am trying to return the results instead of processing the results. For example, I could have a `public static function postsByMaleUsers()` in the `User` model, and calling `User::postsByMaleUsers()` should return a collection of posts by male users only. In which case, the `foreach` loop would not suit me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the posts, then use [`pluck`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck) and [`collapse`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-collapse) to get a flat collection of posts:

```
$users = User::with('posts')->where('gender', 'male')->get();

$posts = $users->pluck('posts')->collapse();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but unfortunately it looks like `pluck` is not implemented on Laravel 4.2. Is there any equivalent method on 4.2 or am I out of luck without upgrading to 5?